# Combine multiple table results into one table in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, search, html-table

I followed a web tutorial on how to build a basic search engine from my database the problem is that when I get the results displayed it shows each result in its own table on my page? I want to merge the results so they all show under one table in html.

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");

if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
header("Location:www.bacons.me");
}
$search_sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username OR FirstName LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
$search_query=mysql_query($search_sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
$search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="Bacons.me">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript">
<meta name="author" content="James Narey">
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Bacons.me</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="http://www.bacons.me/" class="logo-    a">BACONS.ME</a></h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.bacons.me" class="nav-a">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-a">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="search" class="nav-a">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact" class="nav-a">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="handle">Menu<span class="arrow"> ▾</span></div>
    </nav>

<p>Search Results</p>
<?php if(mysql_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
do { ?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Shift</th>
    <th>Agency</th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><?php echo $search_rs['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $search_rs['FirstName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $search_rs['LastName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $search_rs['Shift']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $search_rs['Agency']; ?></td>
</tr>
<br>
</table>
<?php
} while ($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));

} else {
    echo "No results found";
    }


 ?>

 <html>
 <title>results</title>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
      <footer>
    <p class="footer">Website created by James Narey 2015.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...} while ($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));
```

I suspect this is the issue. You're creating a table for each time you fetch the next record. You probably want to do something like this:

```
<table>
<?php if(mysql_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
do { ?>

// fill in table...

<?php
} while ($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query)); 
?>
</table>
```

Notice the table tags are outside the loop, so you'll only create a new row for each record you fetch

Comment: Hi great thank you! This did what I wanted it to do the only trouble now is that it is repeating the header down the search rather than just having one header at the top of the page. Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nevermind! I moved the <th> above the php code and wallah! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put your table tag outside your do while loop, otherwise it would create new table at every iteration of the loop.
Your code structure should be like this

```
<?php if(mysql_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {?>
<table>
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Shift</th>
    <th>Agency</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $search_rs['username']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $search_rs['FirstName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $search_rs['LastName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $search_rs['Shift']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $search_rs['Agency']; ?></td>
</tr>
<br>
<?php
} while ($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place the table tags outside the loop structure:

```
<table> do { ?> <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Shift</th>
    <th>Agency</th> </tr> <tr>
        <td><?php echo $search_rs['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $search_rs['FirstName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $search_rs['LastName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $search_rs['Shift']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $search_rs['Agency']; ?></td> </tr> <br> <?php } while ($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query)); </table>
```